# Should I rely on worker_threads module to parse any input data from HTTP requests?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, worker

For now, [worker_threads](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/worker_threads.html) is a stable module in node.js v12 (LTS).

As we know, e.g. `JSON.parse()` [blocking the Event Loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/#blocking-the-event-loop-json-dos). This is especially important in the context of HTTP requests with POST / PATCH / PUT method. I want to use the `worker_threads` module to solve this problem. But I do not see the recommendations in this regard in the [official Guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/).

So, should I rely on `worker_threads` module to parse any input data from HTTP requests? Should it only be used for large amounts of data? How much large?

Comment: If your JSON string is below, say 1Mb then you are most likely wasting time. Anything above should be measured. Although when dealing with such big data chunks perhaps JSON is not a correct choice to begin with.

Comment: @freakish, why not 0.5 MB or 5 MB? Can it be appreciated somehow?

Comment: From my experience 1Mb is a safe bet. But as I said: you should measure it. It's not hard to make such tests.

Comment: You've asked a question without any quantification for what you're trying to achieve or what your specific objective is.  As such, there is no way to answer. 
How would you describe some specific, measurable objective that you're trying to optimize?  Requests/second you can process?  Seconds/request at some known load?  Plus, what is the size and character of the incoming data?  What is the size and character of the load you're trying to serve?

Comment: Keep in mind that you should only spend time optimizing something when you know exactly what you're trying to optimize for and when you've measured what you have and proven you have a specific problem that needs solving.  Otherwise, you're just doing pre-mature optimization which wastes development time and makes the code more complicated than it may need to be.  The simplest implementation that meets your objectives is the goal.  So, to spend good development time complicating things, you need to prove that you have to and need to.

Comment: And FYI, a different type of solution such as clustering might be simpler and achieve a better result too.  But, you have to know what to measure, prove you have a problem that needs solving and then test out several different solutions by measuring their effectiveness against your goal/objective.